# Rotating javascript image

Tags: javascript

I want to rotate an image IN javascript.
The variable used for the image in javascript is heroImage.
I am using jquery rotate, it works fine only when rotating images in html, but not in javascript.
Normally it looks something like this

```
    $("#image").rotate(angle);
```

But that only works for images created in html.

This is part of the code im currently using

```
var heroImage = new Image();
heroImage.src = "images/hero.png";
```

and its drawn of canvas , if that helps.
the problem is #image can only refer to a html div element afaik.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you some sample code of what you have tried?

Comment: Draw it onto a canvas.

Comment: maybe try [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com). Not too sure what you're actually looking for though, you should clarify. How is your image defined in javascript, as a bitmap, or are you using a library helper function?

Answer (score 2):

If the `heroImage` variable is a string that contains a file name, just create a new image and append it to the DOM before calling `rotate()`, f.ex:

```
var heroImage = 'one.jpg';
var image = new Image();
image.src = heroImage;
$('#image').append(image).rotate(angle);
```

**EDIT**
If the `#image` element is supposed to be the `IMG` itself, try something like:

```
var heroImage = 'one.jpg';
var image = new Image();
image.src = heroImage;
document.body.appendChild(image); // or wherever you want to put it
$(image).rotate(angle);
```

Comment: So, in this case `#image` is a div or similar, not an `<img/>`, correct?

Comment: I assumed so, but it’s hard to tell from the question.